# Press Exit to appear in full screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Why the exit window does not appear in as in picture number two
It appears as full screen as picture neo
This is the code used:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainHomeActivity.this);
    } else {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainHomeActivity.this, AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);}
        builder.setTitle("Thank You");
        builder.setMessage("Thank You For Using Our Application Please Give Us Your Suggestions and Feedback ");
        builder.setNegativeButton("RATE US",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ADD YOUR APPS PACKAGE NAME"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(MainHomeActivity.this, "Thank you for your Rating",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        builder.setPositiveButton("QUIT",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
                    finish();
                }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrnIl.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73VPV.png)

Comment: For it to appear as pic1 you do not need to user AlertDialog.Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
builder.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```